# How to obtain the agent spawn egg in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I would like to experiment with [the agent](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Agent) on the standard (non-education) edition of Minecraft for iOS. It looks like there is only one way to do it without Code Connection - get it 'with an NBT editor'. But what does it mean? What should I modify there? Will I just get the mob or will I be able to program it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a agent "plugin" using the [wsserver library](https://github.com/Sandertv/mcwss). You can use it by going on https://repl.it/@behavingEffort/agent and using the command /connect agent.behavingeffort.repl.co/ws.

You can spawn the agent using the chat command ".agent tp" and you can use the full list of commands from this documentation: https://education.minecraft.net/wp-content/uploads/Code_Connection_API.pdf

Comment: Thanks, sounds great! Should it work with non-educational version of Minecraft installed on iPad? My iPad says 'connection failed'.

Comment: Try to run the command twice, the server sleeps if noone connected to it for a while

Comment: Yes, it works. Many thanks!
Where can I read how it works? Looks like this is some kind of proxy-addon.

Comment: A guy re-coded the whole Code Connection protocol. The code connection basically works by sending messages back and forth between the server and minecraft, the message will include what the purpose of it is (e.g running a command) and the message itself (e.g "/say hello"). Here's the library: https://github.com/Sandertv/mcwss and here's the source code of the agent thing i made with it: https://repl.it/@behavingEffort/agent

Comment: The URL https://repl.it/@behavingEffort/agent is 404. Is this available anywhere else?

Comment: unfortunately I do not have the source code anymore, but it should be quite easy to replicate with the wsserver library: https://github.com/Sandertv/mcwss